# How can I remove the workspace switcher indicator in GNOME shell on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: indicator, workspaces, gnome-shell

I want to remove this annoying workspace switch indicator:

[image: Workspace switch indicator]

I usually use the multiple workspaces to switch quickly and work more efficiently, but this icon doesn't even fade after a few good annoying seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this issue by installing the gnome shell extension: "No Workspace Switcher Popup".

You can find it here:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/758/no-workspace-switcher-popup/